# How pass variables from activity to service without restart service

Tags: java, android

I need send data (ArrayList, Array, String, etc) from my `Activity` to my `Service`. If use `Intent` and `Bundle` nesessary Service restart. I need send data without restart Service (if Service is running use him, if not running start him and send new data).

Also I need same send data from `BroadcastReceiver` to Service.

What is best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Bind](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) Service for that, it is meant for communication between service and other component.

[Example](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Local_Bound_Services_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example)

Comment: Please, get me link to real full simple working example with Activity and Service.

Comment: see an example now in my answer.

Comment: Android Killer, I find example with send data from Service to Activity. But i need send data from Activity to Service. And this is not full example, this is puzzle from many code-pieces :)